# PHP GET don't get vars from URL

Tags: php, json, get

I have a GET request, that looks like this:

```
http://example.com/uemb-tool/files/ajax.php?q=setRooms&i=5+[{%22period_id%22:%225%22,%22room_id%22:%22%22,%22room_name%22:%22CDI%22,%22room_description%22:%22%22,%22days%22:[{%22day_id%22:1,%22day_name%22:%22Montag%22,%22day_checked%22:false},{%22day_id%22:2,%22day_name%22:%22Dienstag%22,%22day_checked%22:false},{%22day_id%22:3,%22day_name%22:%22Mittwoch%22,%22day_checked%22:false},{%22day_id%22:4,%22day_name%22:%22Donnerstag%22,%22day_checked%22:false},{%22day_id%22:5,%22day_name%22:%22Freitag%22,%22day_checked%22:false}],%22specials%22[{%22special_id%22:%221%22,%22special_name%22:%22Sanittsdienst%22,%22special_description%22:%22aktives%20Mitglied%20im%20SchuC3%A4tsdienst%22,%22special_checked%22:false}],%22room_application_possible%22:true,%22room_wage%22:%22%22}]`
```

You can see 2 vars q and i. On my xampp installation worked this all fine, but on the webserver `print_r($_GET)`shows only q. What did I wrong?

Comment: i would `urlencode()` the $i var before its added to the url then decode at the other end. also some security software restricts url lengths (suhosin, 512)

Comment: You should not use GET request for sending JSON data. Use POST or PUT and send it in a request body.

Comment: as suggested above dont use JSON data in GET request

Comment: If you're using JSON in a URL you'll want to look at [Rison](https://github.com/deceze/Kunststube-Rison).